# Is there a cite style "empty"?

Tags: biblatex, citing, natbib

I have really specific conditions as to how I have to cite and want therefore to write each citation manually, while still linking to the reference entry. I'm currently using natbib with agsm, but am willing to switch.

Is there any command that does something like

```
Blabla \customcite[(actually showing this text)]{key}
```

which results in: Blabla (actually showing this text)

Comment: Do you have some constrains to the actual text shown? For example, if you are always mentioning the year in the custom text you can use \citeyear as part of your text. Furthermore, the whole text needs to be a link to the citation?

Comment: First, the text in the square brackets need to link to the reference. And there is no citation style that fits the constraints, as they are way too situational to fit to one bibliography style. I really need the citation style to be empty.

Comment: Since you flagged the question with `biblatex`, you have `\notecite` (and friends) available out of the box.

Comment: @Pywide, ok. Then you need to use `\nocite` to create the citation and `\hyperlink` to point to the reference entry. See my posted answer and let me know if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: As I was pointed out, there is the `\notecite` family of commands from biblatex. The MWE Should be as follows:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{sources.bib}
    @book{mycite,
    author = {Doe, John},
    title = {Example},
    publisher = {Random House},
    year = 2024,
    }
    @book{mycite2,
        author = {Moore, Jane},
        title = {Example of examples},
        publisher = {Random House},
        year = 2023,
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    This is a parencite \parencite{mycite}
        
    This is a \notecite[custom cite]{mycite2}

    \clearpage

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

Ok, I was tinkering a bit in Overleaf and TeXStudio and came with a MWE with the main idea working.

Hope it solves your requirements.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{sources.bib}
    @book{mycite,
    author = {Doe, John},
    title = {Example},
    publisher = {Random House},
    year = 2024,
    }
    @book{mycite2,
        author = {Moore, Jane},
        title = {Example of examples},
        publisher = {Random House},
        year = 2023,
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\NewDocumentCommand{\customcite}{m m}{\hyperlink{cite.\therefsection @#2}{#1}\nocite{#2}}

\begin{document}

        This is a parencite \parencite{mycite}
        
    This is a \customcite{custom cite}{mycite2}

        \clearpage

        \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

You can remove the `filecontents` environment and replace the `bibresource` with your own `bib` file.

Comment: Alas, apparently there's also notecite so my solution is no longer necessary at all.